# HTML5 input validation with function rather than pattern

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a form where some inputs like email get validated with a regex in HTML5. 
I need to validate other inputs where I cannot use a pattern. I need to look into a database and look for duplicates. Can I validate by calling some function rather than using pattern?

I could validate as the user types something by calling some function, but my end goal is to achieve UI consistency. Because the email input is validated using pattern and a regex, the UI is created by the browser, so I wan the same UI when validating other fields where I cannot use regex.

Comment: This is possible to do, but you'd be distancing yourself from HTML5-style validation, especially since your function would have to be asynchronous to look up a database. (I'm 99% certain "pre-HTML5" JS validation frameworks are out there, so you could try any of those)

Comment: You can do it, just do and AJAX request to validate your data against the DB.

Comment: You can use jQuery to easily achieve this effect. You can use the jQuery.change() function to basically validate inputs on the fly using jQuery.ajax(), or the specific jquery.post()/jquery.get() functions.

Comment: I need to display an error message if the user enters a duplicate value. Is it possible to achieve the same UI as with HTML5 since the message is dependent on the browser?

Comment: jac0117, your question in a comment is much more specific and easily answerable (the answer is “no”). but different from the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible! With [setCustomValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity).

You just need to get your input element (either through a callback, or document.getElementBy...) and call

```
element.setCustomValidity('message here')
```

If the input is valid, you can call

```
element.setCustomValidity('')
```

to clear the error message.

For example:

```
<input name='email' onchange='checkEmail(this)'></input>
```

then define checkEmail...

```
function checkEmail(element) {
    ajaxCallToServer(element.value, function callback(hypotheticalResponse) {
        if (hypotheticalResponse.isOk) {
            element.setCustomValidity('');
        } else {
            element.setCustomValidity('Sorry that email is already taken!');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, HTML5 validation has no function concept. It is in principle language-agnostic and does not even postulate JavaScript support in the browser. It supports only the checks described in HTML5 specs.